# conversion of a non correlated sub query to a join statement

Tags: sql-server, performance, subquery, sql-server-2000, query-performance

Is it possible to get rid of the sub query and convert the entire query into a `JOIN` query?

```
SELECT student_id,
       COUNT(attendance)
FROM   student_attendance
WHERE  attendance = 'ABSENT'
GROUP  BY student_id
HAVING COUNT(attendance) = (SELECT max_allowed
                            FROM   configurations);
```

I tried the following:

```
SELECT student_id,
       COUNT(attendance)
FROM   student_attendance,
       configurations c
WHERE  attendance = 'ABSENT'
GROUP  BY student_id
HAVING COUNT(attendance) = c.max_allowed;
```

and got this error:

> Column 'c.max_allowed' is invalid in the HAVING clause because
>   it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

I want to do this for to a possible increase in query speed in case of thousands of records. Is my concern even valid?

**Environment:** SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial query shows that `configurations` must have no more than one row (or it would fail). You *could* rewrite this as a join using

```
SELECT student_id,
       COUNT(attendance)
FROM   student_attendance
       CROSS JOIN configurations c
WHERE  attendance = 'ABSENT'
GROUP  BY student_id
HAVING COUNT(attendance) = MAX(c.max_allowed);
```

Or as

```
SELECT student_id,
       COUNT(attendance)
FROM   student_attendance CROSS JOIN
       configurations c
WHERE  attendance = 'ABSENT'
GROUP  BY student_id, c.max_allowed
HAVING COUNT(attendance) = c.max_allowed;
```

Or as

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   (SELECT student_id,
               COUNT(attendance) AS count_attendance
        FROM   student_attendance
        WHERE  attendance = 'ABSENT'
        GROUP  BY student_id) AS t
       JOIN configuration AS c
         ON t.count_attendance = c.max_allowed;
```

But I don't see any benefit of doing so. The original query is clearer and likely to be equally or more efficient.

The execution plan I see is

[image]

The select against `configurations` is executed once - then the rest of the query is run as an independent sub tree with the final elimination of aggregate rows not matching the `HAVING` happening in the `INNER JOIN`.

To optimise this query you should consider creating an index on `attendance, student_id`. This will allow rows matching the `attendance = 'ABSENT'` predicate to be efficiently identified. And they will be ordered so can be processed by the stream aggregate without needing a sort.

One other option would be to pre-calculate the aggregation using an indexed view.