# how to get total count of partial counts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

An extension to this [Question here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/201538/conversion-of-a-non-correlated-sub-query-to-a-join-statement), how can I fetch the count for ALL the students who have reached their maximum allowed absents.

I tried this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
SELECT student_id,
       COUNT(attendance)
FROM   student_attendance
WHERE  attendance = 'ABSENT'
GROUP  BY student_id
HAVING COUNT(attendance) = (SELECT max_allowed
                            FROM   configurations)
) abc
```

but it is not working and gives this error:

> No column was specified for column 2 of 'abc'.

**Environment:** SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a column name for `COUNT(attendance)` - such as `CountAttendance`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
SELECT student_id,
       COUNT(attendance) as CountAttendance
FROM   student_attendance
WHERE  attendance = 'ABSENT'
GROUP  BY student_id
HAVING COUNT(attendance) = (SELECT max_allowed
                            FROM   [configuration])
) a ;
```

Removing `COUNT(attendance)` from the `SELECT` clause of the subquery should also work (as you found out).

> But why a non-aliased `COUNT` column causes issue?

Because all columns in a subquery should be named/aliased. Some DBMS (and some versions) don't require this, as they provide arbitrary names themselves. Others, like SQL Server, are more restrictive.

You could even have a single column with `SELECT 1 AS c` in the subquery or `SELECT NULL AS c`. The outer query needs only to count rows with `COUNT(*)` so the column list in the subquery is completely irrelevant. What matter are the `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses.